# How to receive text on a Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi set up with an lcd screen. I am trying to receive sms on that. How do I go about it? What is the best way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is dedicated on helping other people issues, but we need some help on narrowing down your problem, not just giving you a ready to go solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup. To send and receive SMS I use a tool called [REST SMS Gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perfness.smsgateway.rest). It is an app for a phone (with an Android OS) which starts a web server on 8080 port. To send or receive a message you just need to execute REST command (after pressing button "Start" in the app). For example, to send a message you need to run the following command:

```
curl -X "PUT" "http://192.168.1.101:8080/v1/sms/?phone=1234&message=message%20to%20send"
```

(In my case server works on 192.168.1.101, your ip can be different - just check what the app shows after pressing button "Start")

To get a list of messages you can use the following command:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://192.168.1.101:8080/v1/sms/"
```

To see more message just play with offset and limit:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://192.168.1.101:8080/v1/sms/?limit=30&offset=10"
```

If you want, you can write your own software. Here is an example in Python:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection 
conn = HTTPConnection('192.168.1.101', '8080') 
conn.request('PUT', '/v1/sms/?phone=123&message=message%20to%20send')
resp = conn.getresponse()
data = resp.read().decode("utf-8")
print(data) # OK if message was sent
```

You can list threads, messages in threads, etc as well - just read the doc included in the app :)